# Convert base class to child class in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm really new to OOP and C# and I'm trying to understand, how I could write my code as DRY as possible. In my ASP.NET MVC 3 Application I have multiple actions (two in this example code) in a controller which all return a different `ViewModel` which are all inheriting the same `BaseViewModel`. This is because I need the same data on every action but with additional properties for each.

I know I could simply create a constructor for `ActionOneViewModel` which receives a `ViewModel` object. But is this the common way to do this? Or are there any alternatives?

**View Models:**

```
class BaseViewModel 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}

class ActionOneViewModel : BaseViewModel 
{
    public bool FooBar { get; set; }
}

class ActionTwoViewModel : BaseViewModel 
{
    public string PingPong { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller Actions:**

```
public ActionResult ActionOne () 
{
    // this doesn't work (of course)
    ActionOneViewModel model = (ActionOneViewModel)createViewModel();
    model.FooBar = true;

    return View(model);
}

public ActionResult ActionTwo () 
{
    // this doesn't work (of course)
    ActionTwoViewModel model = (ActionTwoViewModel)createViewModel();
    model.PingPong = "blub";

    return View(model);
}

private BaseViewModel createViewModel()
{
    BaseViewModel model = new BaseViewModel();

    //
    // doing a lot of stuff here
    //

    return model;
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. Since I don't wanna have any logical code in my models, Gabe's answer is the best solution for me. But I keep those other solutions in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
ActionTwoViewModel model = new ActionTwoViewModel();
model = createViewModel(model);


private BaseViewModel createViewModel(BaseViewModel model)
{
    //
    // doing a lot of stuff here
    //

    return model;
}
```

Comment: Oh my, it really was that easy. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in method or constructor

with that one, no need to have a special "createViewModel" method.

```
class BaseViewModel 
{
    public BaseViewModel() {
     //stuff here
     }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}

class ActionOneViewModel : BaseViewModel 
{
    public ActionOneViewModel (bool fooBar) : base() {
         FooBar = fooBar;
    }
    public bool FooBar { get; set; }
}

class ActionTwoViewModel : BaseViewModel 
{
    public ActionTwoViewModel(string pingPong) :base() {
      PingPong = pingPong;
    }
    public string PingPong { get; set; }
}
```

usage

```
public ActionResult ActionTwo () 
{
    // this doesn't work (of course)
    var model = new ActionTwoViewModel("blub");

    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [base](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (On MSDN), you can call the superclass constructor, then add your stuff for your class.

```
public class ActionOneViewModel : BaseViewModel 
{
    public ActionOneViewModel (bool fooBar) : base()
    {
        //other stuff here
        model.FooBar = fooBar;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `:base()` is the default, the super class constructor will always be called.

Answer (score 1):

With a little generic, this will works :

```
private T CreateViewModel<T>()
    where T : BaseViewModel, new()
{
    BaseViewModel model = new T();
    //doing a lot of stuff here
    return (T)model;
}
```

You can use it like :

```
ActionOneViewModel  model1 = CreateViewModel<ActionOneViewModel>();
ActionTwoViewModel  model2 = CreateViewModel<ActionTwoViewModel>();
```